# Problem calculating the average power of a vector?

Tags: power-spectral-density, math, covariance

I am calculating the average power of a vector. I would like to compare the final expression with the simulation. However, they are not equal. Please help me to point out which steps are wrong. Thank you very much.

Calculate the average power of a vector:

$x(n) = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{L - 1} {\sum\limits_{l = 0}^{L - 1} {\frac{1}{L}{e^{ - j2\pi \left( {\frac{n}{N} - \frac{i}{L}} \right){r_l}}}} } {e^{ - j2\pi \frac{i}{L}l}}s\left( {n- \frac{i}{L}N} \right),n = 0,...,N - 1$

where $s$ is independent and identically distributed data symbols with zero mean and variance $\sigma _s^2$, $r = ({r_0},...,{r_{L - 1}})$ has Gaussian distribution with mean ${\mu _r}$ and variance $\sigma _r^2$, and $\frac{N}{L}$ is integer.

The average power of $x$ is:

$\bar P = \frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{N - 1} {E\left\{ {{{\left| {x\{ n\} } \right|}^2}} \right\}}$ (1)

where

$\begin{array}{l}
E\left\{ {{{\left| {x\{ n\} } \right|}^2}} \right\} = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{L - 1} {\frac{{\sigma _s^2}}{{{L^2}}}} E\left\{ {{{\left| {\sum\limits_{l = 0}^{L - 1} {{e^{ - j2\pi \left( {\frac{n}{N} - \frac{i}{L}} \right){r_l}}}{e^{ - j2\pi \frac{i}{L}l}}} } \right|}^2}} \right\}\\
 = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{L - 1} {\frac{{\sigma _s^2}}{{{L^2}}}} \sum\limits_{l = 0}^{L - 1} {\sum\limits_{m = 0}^{L - 1} E } \left\{ {{e^{ - j2\pi \left( {\frac{n}{N} - \frac{i}{L}} \right)({r_l} - {r_m})}}{e^{ - j2\pi \frac{i}{L}(l - m)}}} \right\}
\end{array}$  (2)

When $l=m$, then $E\left\{ {{{\left| {x\{ n\} } \right|}^2}} \right\} = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{L - 1} {\frac{{\sigma _s^2}}{{{L^2}}}} \sum\limits_{l = 0}^{L - 1} E \left\{ {{e^{ - j2\pi \left( {\frac{n}{N} - \frac{i}{L}} \right)({r_l} - {r_l})}}{e^{ - j2\pi \frac{i}{L}(l - l)}}} \right\} = \frac{{\sigma _s^2}}{{{L^2}}}(L - 1)L = \frac{{\sigma _s^2}}{L}(L - 1)$   (3)

When $l \ne m$, then $\begin{array}{l}
E\left\{ {{{\left| {x\{ n\} } \right|}^2}} \right\} = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{L - 1} {\frac{{\sigma _s^2}}{{{L^2}}}} \sum\limits_{l = 0}^{L - 1} {\sum\limits_{m = 0\atop
m \ne l}^{L - 1} E } \left\{ {{e^{ - j2\pi \left( {\frac{n}{N} - \frac{i}{L}} \right){r_l}}}{e^{ - j2\pi \frac{i}{L}l}}} \right\}\left\{ {{e^{j2\pi \left( {\frac{n}{N} - \frac{i}{L}} \right){r_m}}}{e^{ - j2\pi \frac{i}{L}m}}} \right\}\\
 = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{L - 1} {\frac{{\sigma _s^2}}{{{L^2}}}} ({L^2} - L){\left| {{\Phi _r}\left( {2\pi \left( {\frac{n}{N} - \frac{i}{L}} \right)} \right)} \right|^2} = \frac{{\sigma _s^2}}{L}(L - 1)\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{L - 1} {{{\left| {{\Phi _r}\left( {2\pi \left( {\frac{n}{N} - \frac{i}{L}} \right)} \right)} \right|}^2}} 
\end{array}$    (4)

where ${{\Phi _r}\left( {2\pi \left( {\frac{n}{N} - \frac{i}{L}} \right)} \right)}$ is the characteristic function of the random variable $r$, which is defined as (for Gaussian distribution):

${\left| {{\Phi _r}\left( {2\pi \left( {\frac{n}{N} - \frac{i}{L}} \right)} \right)} \right|^2} = {e^{ - {{\left( {2\pi \left( {\frac{n}{N} - \frac{i}{L}} \right)} \right)}^2}\sigma _r^2}} \approx 1 - 4{\pi ^2}{\left( {\frac{n}{N} - \frac{i}{L}} \right)^2}\sigma _r^2$    (5)

Therefore, from (2), (3), (4), and (5), we have:

$\begin{array}{l}
E\left\{ {{{\left| {x\{ n\} } \right|}^2}} \right\} = \frac{{\sigma _s^2}}{L}(L - 1) + \frac{{\sigma _s^2}}{L}(L - 1)\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{L - 1} {\left( {1 - 4{\pi ^2}{{\left( {\frac{n}{N} - \frac{i}{L}} \right)}^2}\sigma _r^2} \right)} \\
 = \frac{{\sigma _s^2}}{L}(L - 1) + \frac{{\sigma _s^2}}{L}{(L - 1)^2} - \frac{{4{\pi ^2}\sigma _s^2\sigma _r^2}}{L}(L - 1)\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{L - 1} {\left( {\frac{{{n^2}}}{{{N^2}}} - 2\frac{n}{N}\frac{i}{L} + \frac{{{i^2}}}{{{L^2}}}} \right)} \\
 = \frac{{\sigma _s^2}}{L}(L - 1) + \frac{{\sigma _s^2}}{L}{(L - 1)^2} - \frac{{4{\pi ^2}\sigma _s^2\sigma _r^2}}{L}(L - 1)\left( {\frac{{{n^2}}}{{{N^2}}}(L - 1) - 2\frac{n}{N}\frac{{L(L - 1)}}{{2L}} + \frac{{(L - 1)L(2L - 1)}}{{6{L^2}}}} \right)\\
 = \frac{{\sigma _s^2}}{L}(L - 1) + \frac{{\sigma _s^2}}{L}{(L - 1)^2} - \frac{{4{\pi ^2}\sigma _s^2\sigma _r^2}}{L}{(L - 1)^2}\left( {\frac{{{n^2}}}{{{N^2}}} - \frac{n}{N} + \frac{{2L - 1}}{{6L}}} \right)
\end{array}$     (6)

From (1) and (6), the average power of $x$ becomes:

$\begin{array}{l}
\bar P = \frac{{\sigma _s^2}}{L}(L - 1) + \frac{{\sigma _s^2}}{L}{(L - 1)^2} - \frac{{4{\pi ^2}\sigma _s^2\sigma _r^2}}{{NL}}{(L - 1)^2}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{N - 1} {\left( {\frac{{{n^2}}}{{{N^2}}} - \frac{n}{N} + \frac{{2L - 1}}{{6L}}} \right)} \\
 = \frac{{\sigma _s^2}}{L}(L - 1) + \frac{{\sigma _s^2}}{L}{(L - 1)^2} - \frac{{4{\pi ^2}\sigma _s^2\sigma _r^2}}{{NL}}{(L - 1)^2}\left( {\frac{{(N - 1)(2N - 1)}}{{6N}} - \frac{{N - 1}}{2} + \frac{{N(2L - 1)}}{{6L}}} \right)
\end{array}$

Which steps are not correct?

Comment: What's wrong with RMS?

Comment: Hi @DavidK, what do you mean about RMS?

Comment: From your formulas I suppose that $s(t)$ a continuous random process. When computing $E\{|x(n)|^2\}$ why don't you get values of the autocorrelation of $s(t)$? You should have terms like $E\{s(n/N-i/L)s(n/N-j/L)\}$, and I think you just considered $i=j$.

Comment: Hi @MattL., indeed, $s(t)$ is not a continuous random process, I assume it as independent and identically distributed data symbols. So, there is still autocorrelation of $s(t)$?
P/s: I will edit $s(t)$ in question to avoid misunderstanding. Thank you for your help.

Comment: But obviously the argument of $s$ is not integer, is it? At least I thought that $(n/N-i/L)$ is the argument of $s$.

Comment: @MattL.: you are right, the argument of $s$ can be not integer. So, I edited my question again with some assumptions. I also run again the simulation and compare it with the final above expression. However, they are not still identical. I still do not find "the bug" in the above process. You have any suggestion?

Comment: @StevenHuynh I think I was about to tell you to use RMS in the wrong way, so you can ignore me :)